# Titanium Alloy with Android Emulator on Windows 10

Tags: windows, android-emulator, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I'm having huge problems with Titanium Alloy on Windows 10. I am using the Atom editor to write my apps. Whenever I execute `ti build`, enter the command up to 10(**!!!**) times until an Android device can be found.
For the Android emulator I get an error message as follows:

```
    [Error] Failed to install apk on "emulator-5554"
    [Error] Error: device not found
```

I tried the commands `ti build -p android`, `ti build -p android -T emulator` and `ti build -p android -T emulator -C emulator-5554 --log-level info`. I also tried starting the emulator manually from `avd.exe`. I deleted the `AVD` and created a new one, too

When a device (*USB debugging enabled*) is connected, i tried `ti build -p android -T device` and `ti build -p android -T device -C XT1032`, where `XT1032` is the name of the device. I get an error message as follows:

```
    [ERROR] Unable to find any devices
```

I didn't try so far if the device will be found after some more tries.
When executing the commands, I tried all 4 combinations:

- emulator off, device disconnected
- emulator off, device connected
- emulator on, device disconnected
- emulator on, device connected

I uninstalled `Titanium`, `Android SDK`, `NodeJS` and `Java` and deleted all folders of them. I removed all registry entries, too. Then I installed everything again, `Titanium` at last. Same problem.
I am using `Java` *32 bit* (*v8.0.1020.14*), `NodeJS` *v4.2.6* (also tried *v6.3.0*, but *v4.2.x* is recommend), `Android SDK` (`SDK Tools` *v25.1.7*, `SDK Platform-tools` *24.0.1* and `SDK Build-tools` *21.1.2*. I also tried `SDK Build-tools` *24.0.1*, but *21.x.x* is recommend) and `Titanium` (`SDK` *v6.0.0.v20160719180254*, `CLI`*v5.0.9*).

I modified my environment variables as follows:
*PATH:*
`C:\android-sdk\tools;C:\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\android-sdk\ndk-bundle;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk<version>\bin`
*JAVA_HOME:*
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk<version>`
*ANDROID_SDK_HOME:*
`C:\android-sdk`
I had to set *ANDROID_SDK_HOME* and `C:\android-sdk\ndk-bundle`, otherwise the NDK and the AVDs wouldn't be found by `ti setup check`.

Here is a screenshot of `ti setup check`: [link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KTWL.png)
I don't know why *https://www.google.com* is unreachable. Furthermore, `Intel HAXM` **is installed**. I even reinstalled it without success. The previous installation of `Titanium` could find it...

Thanks for your help!

**TLDNR: my Titanium Alloy installation has problems finding devices. It only works from time to time without any obvious pattern**

Comment: I have less trouble finding the emulator when restarting it after every use with the AVD manager. Additionaly, I select "wipe user data" before launching it again.
Nonetheless, I still have problems with finding the emulator. After setting up my machine for creating nativ modules with Titanium and NDK, it got even worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process terminates after building the `APK` file. If the emulator is running, it is possible to manually install the `APK`. Use this command in the `Command Line`:

```
    <Android SDK folder>\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 install -r -d <project path>\<project folder>\build\android\bin\<project name>.apk
```

The *project name* is equal to the *project folder* name. After installing the `APK`, the application can be started manually in the emulator.

Nonetheless, there are still a lot of issues when developping on Windows 10... I think this forces me to switch to a MAC.